# PHP - changing metadata of a JPEG

Tags: php

Or other image file. Can this be done in a (fairly) simple way using PHP?

I'm coding a website that will allow users to upload photos, but I know JPEGs are notorious for their metadata and ideally I'd like to strip all images uploaded of metadata, either by removal or replacement with junk text.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384962/writing-exif-data-in-php

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to strip most of the exif data quickly and easily without using a library to specifically write it, you can 'resave' the image using gd:

```
$file = 'myjpg.jpg';
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagejpeg($im, 'myjpg2.jpg');
```

Maybe not the best/prettiest solution, but it accomplishes what you want without adding additional libraries.

Comment: +1 Not 100% *related* to the question, but a nice way to get rid off exif data

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this extension for PHP: http://lsolesen.github.io/pel/

Answer (score -1):

i use getID3 library for this. it makes it quite easy

http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

it works with al lot of file extentions
for a demo click here:
[demo](http://www.getid3.org/demo/)

Comment: No, this won't do - the OP is asking to CHANGE the metadata not READ it, which is what getID3 does