# Add details to image file with PHP

Tags: php, image, fileinfo, imagecreatefrompng

How can file details like Authors, Copyright etc can be added to a image file with PHP ?

Example/Screenshoot of details:[image]

I created a script that takes a picture, adds to it in the right top corner the copyright and a ID number from the database automatically then it exports it to jpeg or png depending on the original image format.
I also want to add "Copyright" and "Authors" details to the image file, so they will be visible when a users click "Properties" on windows or other OS etc.

Comment: This is known as "metadata"; for JPEG images, it is stored in a format called EXIF. Those terms might help you in searching for solutions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384962/writing-exif-data-in-php

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to add that data? If someone copys your picture into e.g. Photoshop and save it, the data is not saved.

Comment: @IMSoP thank's I did not knew it was called metadata.

Comment: @putvande I want to add all this so I can identify the user in my database in case the pictures are uploaded on other websites. I know the user can remove all my current id's from everywhere but I want to make it as hard as possible from them. Maybe you got a better idea for my problem?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP haven't function to write exif data. You must use an external function/class.

You can use :

[PEL - PHP Exif Library](http://lsolesen.github.io/pel/) - A library for reading and writing Exif headers in JPEG and TIFF images using PHP

Or [mogrify](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/mogrify.html) on command line. See "[How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)" to use mogrify.