# Can i save Geo location in Images using PHP

Tags: php, geolocation

I want to save GEOLOCATION in image using php.
Say i have LAT and LNG and want to save in image so google can find image and show on map.

How can i do that..
I tried many way but get nothing.

anyone know, help me.

Comment: `create table foo (lat float, long float)`.

Comment: i don't want to save in db. want to save in image itself.

Comment: You will need to write this data to the images EXIF.  This can be challenging but this library for reading and writing EXIF will definitely help you.

Comment: Have you looked at ImageMagick:http://www.imagemagick.org/ to see what they offer?

Comment: How i write GPS data to images EXIF. I try and save postcode, city and country but not save the GPS data. If anyone have sample code please paste here so i can get idea from that.

Comment: Check these links

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384962/writing-exif-data-in-php
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image

Good luck.

Comment: Or see: http://sharpbang.wordpress.com/2013/08/18/adding-exif-data-using-php

Comment: [PelTag](http://lsolesen.github.io/pel/doc/PEL/PelTag.html) seems to have all Geo data tags you need. It seems that [PEL](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel) is not maintained , but it should still work.